# d3 static Cubism chart - can't get data input right

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

I'm trying to make a static cubism chart like this http://bl.ocks.org/bae25/10797393

The csv file ("cubism_test.csv") looks something like this:

date,one,two,three,four,five

2018-06-01,132.54,18.44,68.36,0,56.63

2018-06-02,146.64,19.18,71.74,0,59.66

2018-06-03,160.77,117.98,75.15,0,62.71

2018-06-04,193.29,171.53,78.59,0,65.76

2018-06-05,275.92,78.64,82.05,0,68.82

```
<script>
// create context and horizon
var context = cubism.context()
                    .size(30)
                .stop();
var horizon = context.horizon()
                     .extent([0,2]);

d3.csv("cubism_test.csv", function(data)
{
    var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
    data.forEach(function(d, i)
    {
    d.date = format.parse(d.date);
    d.one= +d.one;
    d.two= +d.two;
    d.three= +d.three;
    d.four= +d.four;
    d.five= +d.five;
    })
    console.log(data);

// define metric accessor
   context.metric(function(start,stop,step,callback)
   {
        var values = data;
        console.log(values);
       callback(null, values);
   }, name);



d3.select("#graph").selectAll(".horizon")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "horizon")
      .call(horizon);

    // set rule
    d3.select("#body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "rule")
      .call(context.rule());

// set focus
context.on("focus", function(i) {
    d3.selectAll(".value")
        .style( "right", i == null ? null : context.size() - i + "px");
});
// set axis 
var axis = context.axis()
d3.select("#graph").append("div").attr("class", "axis").append("g").call(axis);


});
</script>
```

Obviously this isn't working, but I don't know to fix it. I can't find a proper recourse on how to work with d3 data. The ones I've found are very basic and tell you how to use data to make simple circles, but not time series.

I don't know how to tell d3 to use the column headers as names or get it to use the values in the columns as the values for each cubism/horizon chart.

Your advice would be highly appreciated.